# htaccess for angular deployment with godaddy not working

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, angular-cli

I am trying to deploy my angular project to one of my servers, I have moved to  **publich_html/XX/YY** directory

When I try to access the application all the URL redirect is working fine, but when I try to refresh the URL I am getting 404 error, so I did some research on the internet and found suggestions to resolve with **.htaccess** file, so I have created the following

```
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

and uploaded to the same directory(`publich_html/XX/YY`), but still i am getting same 404 error on the refresh, can you any help to get fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?/$1 [QSA,L]


The last line is the solution
```

Comment: Please consider providing an explanation : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Only include 4 spaces before lines of code. The last sentence in your answer is not code, so remove the spaces before it. Do the same with your other text if it's not code

Comment: Finally I have got it working by this answer, thank you so much